# jqassistant how to skip some of the plugins

Tags: jqassistant

I want to use `jqassistant` to create a dependency matrix of the application.
Currently all the plugins are executed by default.
This results in lot of unwanted data.
Is it possible to configure the plugins which I want to execute.
For eg: If I want to capture only the class level dependencies using `jqassistant`, Can I perform a scan only to get the class level informations (Any options in the scan command)?

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet possible but has already been discussed as a potential feature request. There would be two options:

1. Allow skipping whole plugins which are deployed during scan using a configuration property, e.g. "plugin.java.skip=true". This could be solved in a generic way for all plugins.
2. Make specific plugins configurable to allow specifying their "depth" of scanning. There could be again two options:

   - using something like profiles, e.g. "java.plugin.profile=full" or "java.plugin.profile=dependencies"
   - specifying the label and relation types, e.g. "java.plugin.label.include=Type,Field,Method", "java.plugin.relation.include=DEPENDS_ON,EXTENDS,IMPLEMENTS"

What do you think?

Comment: It would be good to have a combination of both. In our case we need only specific features within the java plugin. I could see that you have many scanner plugins for java. Another option is to configure these sub plugins. If sub plugins can be configured it will result in less processing which may be better than limiting the database writes based on configured labels and relations.

Comment: Can you describe the level of information you need? If yes I'd ask you to create an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/buschmais/jqassistant/issues). Would be a good fit for 1.2.0. Just another question: are you scanning using the CLI or Maven plugin?